# Just installed ubuntu 14.04 but after restart it wont boot

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04, system-installation

I used a live USB to install Ubuntu 14.04 and completely erase windows 8.1, the installation went fine but when I restarted the computer Ubuntu wouldn't boot from my HDD, instead it came up with try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu so I restarted without the live usb plugged in and I got an error message **Reboot and select a proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press any key**.

I read a lot of posts about people that had similar problems but so far none of the solutions that worked for them have worked for me.

I also ran boot-repair but that didn't fix the problem either.

Here is the link from boot-repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/7763898/

Please any help would be appreciated.

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite U50D-A notebook with AMD A6-5200 processor

Comment: Are you booting in EFI mode? Is secure boot disabled?

Comment: I am typing on a Toshiba Satalite too, I'm pretty sure they are suppored (this is a pro L20). Is there another USB plugged in? That was a problem I have. I would advise disconnecting all peripheral devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very top of boot repair info you posted it says you have two disks

1. /dev/sda (apparently your hard drive)
2. /dev/sdb (apparently your USB stick)

`/dev/sda` has an EFI boot partition and `/dev/sdb` has an MBR boot loader.

### Check boot device

Boot your computer and go to BIOS by pressing one of:

- F1
- F2
- DEL
- ESC
- F10

And make sure you are booting from your hard disk.

### Check EFI partition

According to 
[Ubuntu UEFI documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_partition), the *EFI System partition* should have a **'boot'** flag. According to the boot repair info you posted, your partition does not have it.

**To fix**: boot from Live USB and run **gparted**. From there you can edit your partition table and add the 'boot' flag.

Comment: I had a look at my BIOS the boot order is HDD then USB so I dont think thats the problem.

Comment: @jake90: Nice :) Since the problem is fixed, please mark my answer as accepted. It will help other people to find an answer here, and it will help me increase my reputation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or a similar problem. Solution: When installing from the USB  select install alongside Ubuntu. I think I was actually reinstalling to the USB each time. 
This worked for me after 3 days of reinstalling, changing boot options testdisk, and as many other things I could find.