# Tried to install Ubuntu, now computer won't boot, HELP!

Tags: 14.04, acer

I have a new Acer Aspire S7. I tried to install Ubuntu, **alongside with Windows 8**, but i messed up in the middle, and now i can't even run Windows 8. I'm desperated, when i turn the computer on, it asks me to enter a bootable device. I made a backup with the Acer tool, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know what to do.

I leave you the report of what boot-repair returned: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8520860/

Comment: Which installation instructions did you use?

Comment: A little bit of this tutorials: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2171029 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2121187v https://plus.google.com/+SoaresChen/posts/e4izLiBKamo http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2108450                  Now i'm stuck and don't know what to do :(

Comment: This seems very similar to http://askubuntu.com/q/493051/62612. Check if your EFI partition is missing the **boot** flag.