# No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda

Tags: 14.04, grub2, lubuntu, windows-8

I just did a `boot-repair` because I can't run windows 8.1 from the grub (I see many options but none works) and I got this result:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9558801/

My question is : Should I care about the following message :

```
No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
```

Is it the origin of the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using **UEFI booting** and GPT partitions (the newer way). So you can ignore the message about the missing MBR.

I suggest running `gparted` and checking if your `/dev/sda2` partition has the **boot** flag. For some reason, that seems like a common problem. I've [answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/493060/62612) a similar question previously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just checked with `gparted`: `/dev/sda2` does have the boot flag (and only that one).

Answer (score 2):

**Problem solved!**

I just had to disable `Secure boot` in the `bios` and now I can boot both in Linux (Lubuntu) and Windows.

I still have 5 entries for Windows, some work, others don't and I don't know why... As long as it works :D.