# can't boot to ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I tried to install ubuntu on my computer, but something terrible happened. Now I can't boot into ubuntu . I tried to install Ubuntu on another partition, it succeed. But after rebooting, it automatically windows, can not read installed systems.The boot menu doesn't appear on the screen. But when i hold down shift key i manage to enter in ubuntu. In ubuntu i also installed boot repair and it gives the url:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12335843/

please someone help me. 
Thank you

Comment: I have done it already but it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: "something terrible happened?" What, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

So you are using your system with DUAL boot, Winodws+Ubuntu.
It's a pretty common problem with dual boot and seems to be an issue with GRUB boot loader.

You can repair it by going to GRUB boot menu and open the os in recovery mode (check this article about [How to repair Ubuntu](https://www.experthoot.com/how-to-repair-ubuntu-if-it-wont-boot/)).
You can also choose to install a fresh copy of your system via keeping your old files.

Better to choose two different partitions, one for windows and another for Ubuntu while you create a dual boot system. and don't forget to turn off **UEFI booting**.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562857/no-boot-loader-is-installed-in-the-mbr-of-dev-sda) similar to your problem?

If it is, then try disabling secure boot in bios as the OP suggests.