# Clean install of 14.04.3 after restart won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

I just formatted and installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 on the full HDD (i.e. no partitions) and my computer doesn't boot up, it just hangs. Well actually it's very temperamental...

Anyway, it wouldn't start at all straight after installation, so I tried to boot from the "live usb" that I used to install Ubuntu and the boot time was cripplingly slow so I restarted the laptop. Then when it restarted it got as far as the unetbootin menu, so I chose to start ubuntu from the usb, then I got a kernel panic. I restarted and got another kernel panic. Then I restarted and it all worked, I had ubuntu running via the install usb so I ran boot-repair [see: snip ]
after I finished boot-repair, I restarted and the laptop just hung on a black screen with a small white cursor line in the top left. Then I restarted and it was very slow but it actually started Ubuntu! Then I restarted and after 7.5 minutes it said "BOOT FAILED' and started trying to boot an irrelevant CD I have in the drive. Then I restarted and the same thing happened! :(

The laptop is a snip.

I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493051/just-installed-ubuntu-14-04-but-after-restart-it-wont-boot) but I don't understand my boot-repair paste well enough to know what to do. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Remove any external media connected to your laptop, then try selecting a different kernel from "Advanced Options" in Grub Menu and also post the result.

Comment: In grub's advanced options there are two to choose from:
*  ubuntu, with linux 3.19.0-25-generic. AND;
   ubuntu, with linux 3.19.0-25-generic (recovery mode)

Comment: What are those?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I booted recovery mode and it loaded pretty fast to the recovery menu. From the recovery menu I chose to update GRUB. When I restarted it worked perfectly. Then I restarted to check if it was working consistently, and it got past the Toshiba screen with the BIOS option, but then hung on a black screen, and didn't get as far as GRUB... What seems to be happening a lot, it boots past BIOS, the screen turns purple (blank) and I can hear the HDD working, then the screen turns black (blank) at the same time as the HDD becomes very quiet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the very best of my knowledge the issue was caused by a faulty HDD, I discovered damaged sectors after running various tests.