# Reboot and select proper Boot Device after ubuntu 16.04 installation wiping Windows 8

Tags: boot, 16.04, windows

I have been trying to solve a problem with my UBUNTU 16.04 LTS installation.  After the installation and trying to restart my computer the following message appears:

Reboot and select proper Boot Device
Insert Boot Media in selected device and press a key

I have looked for help on-line for a while, but no solutions seems to work. I also ran boot-repair but that didn't fix the problem either.

Here is the link from boot-repair http://paste2.org/PeYm6gAt

I also ran the [gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493051/just-installed-ubuntu-14-04-but-after-restart-it-wont-boot/493060#493060) to check that the EFI partion has the boot Flag as suggested in the link.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 17 days..

My computer is a desktop  acer aspire x3950 with windows 8 and EFI boot

1. Make your Windows recovery just in case.  I did not and I have to keep looking for a solution for long period without even be able to work in my computer. At one point I really just wanted to recover my computer..
2. Create a bootable usb.

This is the important part.  I have create a bootable USB with disk creator in UBUNTU without taking into consideration that my computer boot with EFI mode.  After the installation and   computer reboot I got the message: Reboot and select proper Boot Device

I have tried several things, in particular, I used the Boot repair tool.

**SOLUTION:**

2.1  Follow the General Principles in [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)  In particular, disable fast boot.

2.2. Create the bootable usb following the steps in [How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media/)

I  created this usb using [RUFUS](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) with GPT partition for UEFI

3. Install ubuntu using the USB and restart your computer

Done!!!

Comment: Most Acer require you to set a UEFI password and enable "Trust" on the Ubuntu .efi boot files. http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot